# .net returned string getting truncated

Tags: c#, dll

I am returning an html string as return value of a function. The return string is somewhat long (but nothing compared to limit of string datatype). But the returned string is getting truncated.

I tried to convert it to StringBuilder with no benefit.

P.S. My class is inside a .dll and I am trying to access it from outside,

What's wrong and what should I do?

I am consuming here:

```
        string st = asso.getHtmlReport();

        FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("file.html");

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        sw.Write(st);
```

This is the string

```
        public string getHtmlReport()
    {
        string html = "<html><head><title>Association</title></head><body>" +
    "<table >" +
        "<tr align=\"left\">" +
        "<th>t</th>" +
        "<th>" + name1 + "</th>" +
        "<th>Avg rise</th>" +
        "<th>" + name2 + "</th>" +
        "<th>Avg rise</th>" +
        "<th>Difference</th>" +
        "<th>Direction</th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>"+
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(t) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(series1) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(avg1) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top>" +
            seriesPrint(series2) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(avg2) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(diff) +
        "</td>" +
        "<td style=\"padding-left:10px;padding-right:20px;\" valign=\"top\">" +
            seriesPrint(dir) +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>"+ "</table>" +
    "<div style=\"padding:10px; position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; width:300px; border:this solid black; background-color:Black; color:White;\">" +
        "<span style=\" font-weight:bolder; font-size: 2em; color: White;\">Results</span><br />" +
        "<span style=\" font-weight:bolder; font-size: 1em; color: White;\">Total records : " + series1.Length + "</span><br />" +
        "<span style=\" font-weight:bolder; font-size: 1em; color: White;\">Average error : " + avgError() + "</span><br />" +
        "<span style=\" font-weight:bolder; font-size: 1em; color: White;\">Together : " + support() + "</span><br />" +
        "<span style=\" font-weight:bolder; font-size: 1em; color: White;\">Opposite : " + (series1.Length - support()) + "</span><br />" +
    "</div>" +
"</body></html>";
        return html;

    }
```

Comment: Where are you viewing the truncated the string?  The debugger may truncate really long strings when it displays them, but that doesn't mean the memory value is not accurate.

Comment: Some what long. hmm.. how long? .Net doesnt propose any string max size.

Comment: No, we need the function that produces the string.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I am writing it to a file.

Comment: if you check the length of the string in code, is it correct?  The problem might be that you're not flushing your stream, so the entire buffer is not being written.  Try adding "sw.Flush();" after you write and before you close the stream.

Comment: @Jason oh yes.. how could I forget. Kindly add that as an answer. Ill mark it best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your stream after you write it.

```
sw.Flush();
```